# Using WWW::Mechanize to pull authenticated html page getting javascript error

Tags: perl

I had written a perl script last year which connected to cbssports.com, authenticated, then pulled down all the scores for our fantasy football league.  Even though it uses javascript I was able to just pull the right html pages to get what I needed.  But something changed and now all I keep getting is 'You need to enable JavaScript to run this app'.  I am using WWW::Mechanize but I also tried to use LWP::UserAgent.  When I use the latter I can see that the authentication works and it lists a '302 Found' link to the document.  But if I do a get on that link it goes right back to the javascript error.  But what is really strange is that with the LWP useragent check after the authentication completes, I skip going to the 302 found link, if I go to the live scores page it works, if I go to the schedule page (where I prefer), it gets the javascript error.  Not sure why.  Anyway, is there anything else I can add to this to help diagnose this.  Here is the small code so far.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $url = "https://www.cbssports.com/login?xurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmyleague.football.cbssports.com%2Fschedule%2Ffull";
my $username = "myuser";
my $password = "mypass";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->agent_alias('Linux Mozilla');
$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_id('login_form');
$mech->field("userid", $username);
$mech->field("password", $password);
$mech->click;

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
```

Now if I use the LWP::UserAgent method this is what I am seeing.  It doesn't appear to be doing the redirects.

```
my $urllive = "http://myleague.football.cbssports.com/scoring/live";
my $urlfull = "http://myleague.football.cbssports.com/schedule/full";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->cookie_jar({ file => "$ENV{HOME}/.cookies.txt" });
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');
$ua->credentials("$url", "realm-name", '$username','$password');
my $max = $ua->max_redirect;
$ua->max_redirect( 7 );
my $resp = $ua->post("$url",
   { "form_id" => "login_form",
     "userid" => "$username",
     "password" => "$password",
   });
print $resp->content;


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>302 Found</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Found</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.cbssports.com/registration?master_product=150&amp;user_action=user_signin&amp;end=http%3A%2F%2Fmyleague.football.cbssports.com%2Fschedule%2Ffull%3Ftid%3D1600180459%26login%3Dconfirmed">here</A>.<P>
```

At this point if I do the get for $urllive it works, if I do it for $urlfull it gets the javascript error.  I know this is a long thread but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a good chance they've updated to a more modern website with a client-side frontend application and API calls. Log into the website in a browser and look at the network tab of your developer tools for API calls. There's a good chance once you have a session token you can pull their APIs directly to query data. Also check their terms and services to see if they allow this.